# Why doesnt it show hello by clicking button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-button, toast

I want a program that includes an EditText and a button.I want to show a message by clicking the button if the EditText string equals " h" .
But it doesnt work.It prints "hello" whether EditText input equals "h" or not.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.*;
import android.text.*;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    
    

    EditText tex=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etx);
    final String vorodi=tex.getText().toString();
    
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                
                if (vorodi.equals("h")){
                    
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                   "hello", 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                
            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: let me see... add this to your program and it will surely work!

Comment: share your code snippet.

Comment: It doesnt let me share my code! It says not well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
final String vorodi=tex.getText().toString();
```

inside your `onClick()` function so that you're capturing the contents of the edittext on click rather than when setting up the user interface in `onCreate()`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very very much my friend.

Comment: @Allianz Please accept it as answer if it helped you.